# can odorous VOCs be removed by an ionizing air purifier?

Tags: air, molecules

I am considering replacing my IQAir HealthPro 250 air purifier by an Electrolux EAP300. According to the marketers, the EAP300 has PlasmaWave(TM) technology that supposedly removes odours from the air by mimicking conditions occurring in the ionosphere.

I suppose if it works at all, it works by breaking down large-chain odorous volatile organic compounds (VOCs) into smaller-chain non-odorous VOCs.

Can this kind of technology, if properly implemented, be an efficient way of removing odors from indoor air? Or is there any fundamental limitation such as requiring hydrogen as an input to terminate the broken bonds just like in hydrocracking, or producing so much ozone as a side effect that it would be unhealthy?

The device consumes less than 10 watts of power at the air flow level I'm planning to use it. Is there any minimum bound for power consumption by this kind of air purification technology, given the typical indoor air VOC levels? If so, how large the power consumption is expected to be for efficient operation?

According to the manufacturer, it produces less than 0.050 ppm of ozone. How much ozone an efficient air purifier operating in the same way would produce, i.e. can I deduce from the low ozone production level that the device is inefficient?

Comment: This is probably more closely aligned with [chemistry](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) than physics.

Answer (score 2):

[According to what little](http://www.iqair.com/international/home-air-purifiers/healthproseries/features#hyper) the specification gives away, this is a filtering system that removes *particulate matter* from air.

VOCs do not manifest themselves as particles but rather as (*molecular*) vapour which cannot be filtered out with traditional filtering media, no matter how efficient otherwise they may be.

Specific [Molecular sieves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_sieve) *can* remove molecules but the specification does't mention them.

> According to the manufacturer, it produces less than 0.050 ppm of ozone. How much ozone an efficient air purifier operating in the same way would produce, i.e. can I deduce from the low ozone production level that the device is inefficient?

Going by the bar chart comparison on that page, the low ozone level is presented as a USP. Ozone is indeed not very healthy but as a strong oxidiser and used in the right conditions it can react with VOCs. Presumably this is how 'air purifying ozonators' are supposed to work. The low ozone generation of this device obviously here precludes the use of ozone as a VOC scavenger.

On balance I'm very sceptical with regards to this machine's capacity to remove VOCs from any air stream but need to **emphasise** that only relevant empirical testing can answer that question definitively.

As regards the Electrolux EAP350 and 'PlasmaWave (TM)' technology, [this page states](https://www.alza.co.uk/electrolux-eap300-d1470351.htm?kampan=pricespy_UK_Air_&_Water_Purifiers_&utm_source=pricespy_UK&utm_medium=product&utm_campaign=pricespy_UK_Air_&_Water_Purifiers):

> **Air Purifier Electrolux EAP300**:
>   Powerful and at the same time Silent Electrolux air purifier EAP300 features high efficiency in cleaning a good price-performance ratio. HEPA filter captures almost all types of air pollutants. This purifier is also equipped with prefilter , electrostatic main filter and charcoal filter for eliminating odors. In normal mode only works when 35 W And therefore its energy intensity is low. It is also very quiet - 25 decibels in the bedroom mode is much quieter than a refrigerator.

'PlasmaWave' is of course a purely snazzy marketing term, designed to *blind with science' and no plasma in the scientific sense of the word is involved here. However, the use of a (presumed *active*) charcoal filter *does hold out the promise of part or complete removal of VOCs*. But the same caveat formulated with respect to HealthPro 250 machines also holds here: only testing can truly tell.

Comment: Actually, the PlasmaWave(TM) technology is in EAP300, not in HealthPro 250. PlasmaWave is indeed marketed as an odour-removing technology, and I'm very sceptical. The HealthPro has 2.5 kg activated charcoal filter in addition to the HyperHepa filter, which I suppose could be efficient, but see my other question about saturation by atmospheric methane.

Comment: @juhist: ok, I'll have a look at the Electrolux type.

Comment: @juhist: edit made.